# How can we add a default location in the tweet

Tags: android, twitter, social-networking, twitter-fabric

I am using fabric to connect to twitter using my android application.

My question is:

How do we add a default location in my tweet?

I can put a default hashtag in the tweet(obviously that is editable),i also want to put a default location because i want user to use my product's hashtag and the location of the store.

Is there any workaround for this??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter's [Developer Agreement and Policy](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/terms/agreement-and-policy) requires certain behaviour around location data. Many users are sensitive about sharing location information.

> If your Service adds location information to users’ Tweets:
>
> - Disclose when you add location information, whether as a geotag or annotations
>   data, and whether you add a place or specific coordinates.
> - Comply with
>   Geo Developers Guidelines if your application allows users to Tweet
>   with their location.

That said, Twitter's Fabric Twitter Kit for Android invokes the Twitter app installed on the device to provide a Tweet Composer, so the user will need to choose to add the location directly in the UI, since there's no built-in way to switch that on by default.

Comment: Thanks Andy. I posted a question on twitter's developer forum too(you replied there too :) ). That's why I wrote "workaround" in my question. Really appreciate your response. Cheers!